Minecraft Mod deployment exception
I am trying to create a Minecraft mod for Minecraft Version 1.20.1 using Forge 47.2.8 but since I added my 2nd block, Minecraft suddenly started crashing upon startup.
Block Register Code:
package net.tryinc.narutomod.block;

import net.minecraft.world.item.BlockItem;
import net.minecraft.world.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.Blocks;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.state.BlockBehaviour;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.IEventBus;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.DeferredRegister;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.ForgeRegistries;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.RegistryObject;
import net.tryinc.narutomod.NarutoMod;
import net.tryinc.narutomod.item.ModItems;

import java.util.function.Supplier;


public class ModBlocks {
    public static final DeferredRegister<Block> BLOCKS =
            DeferredRegister.create(ForgeRegistries.BLOCKS, NarutoMod.MOD_ID);

    // Flag symbol identifiers are the First and Last letter of the Town/Clan
    // KE = Konohagakure
    // UA = Uchiha
    public static final RegistryObject<Block> UA_FLAG_SYMBOL = registerBlock("ua_flag",
            () -> new Block(BlockBehaviour.Properties.copy(Blocks.BLUE_WOOL)));
    public static final RegistryObject<Block> UA_OAK_LOG_SYMBOL = registerBlock("ua_oak_flag",
            () -> new Block(BlockBehaviour.Properties.copy(Blocks.OAK_LOG)));


    private static <T extends Block> RegistryObject<T> registerBlock(String name, Supplier<T> block) {
        RegistryObject<T> toReturn = BLOCKS.register(name, block);
        registerBlockItem(name, toReturn);
        return toReturn;
    }
    private static <T extends Block> RegistryObject<Item> registerBlockItem(String name, RegistryObject<T> block) {
        return ModItems.ITEMS.register(name, () -> new BlockItem(block.get(), new Item.Properties()));
    }
    public static void register(IEventBus eventBus) {
        BLOCKS.register(eventBus);
    }

}

Error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot get property EnumProperty{name=axis, clazz=class net.minecraft.core.Direction$Axis, values=[x, y, z]} as it does not exist in Block{minecraft:air}

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Registry Object not present: narutomod:ua_oak_flag

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot get property EnumProperty{name=axis, clazz=class net.minecraft.core.Direction$Axis, values=[x, y, z]} as it does not exist in Block{minecraft:air}

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Registry Object not present: narutomod:ua_oak_flag

I did expect Minecraft to start and the Block to be available in-game.
Logs:

A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Render thread
Suspected Mods: NONE
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraftforge.registries.GameData.postRegisterEvents(GameData.java:330) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.2.8_mapped_parchment_2023.09.03-1.20.1-recomp.jar%23190%23197!/:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraftforge.common.ForgeStatesProvider.lambda$new$4(ForgeStatesProvider.java:25) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.2.8_mapped_parchment_2023.09.03-1.20.1-recomp.jar%23190%23197!/:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.ModLoader.handleInlineTransition(ModLoader.java:217) ~[fmlcore-1.20.1-47.2.8.jar%23195!/:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.ModLoader.lambda$dispatchAndHandleError$19(ModLoader.java:209) ~[fmlcore-1.20.1-47.2.8.jar%23195!/:?] {}
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178) ~[?:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.ModLoader.dispatchAndHandleError(ModLoader.java:209) ~[fmlcore-1.20.1-47.2.8.jar%23195!/:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.ModLoader.lambda$gatherAndInitializeMods$13(ModLoader.java:183) ~[fmlcore-1.20.1-47.2.8.jar%23195!/:?] {}
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[?:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.ModLoader.gatherAndInitializeMods(ModLoader.java:183) ~[fmlcore-1.20.1-47.2.8.jar%23195!/:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.client.loading.ClientModLoader.lambda$begin$1(ClientModLoader.java:70) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.2.8_mapped_parchment_2023.09.03-1.20.1-recomp.jar%23190%23197!/:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraftforge.client.loading.ClientModLoader.lambda$createRunnableWithCatch$4(ClientModLoader.java:90) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.2.8_mapped_parchment_2023.09.03-1.20.1-recomp.jar%23190%23197!/:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraftforge.client.loading.ClientModLoader.begin(ClientModLoader.java:70) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.2.8_mapped_parchment_2023.09.03-1.20.1-recomp.jar%23190%23197!/:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.<init>(Minecraft.java:464) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.2.8_mapped_parchment_2023.09.03-1.20.1-recomp.jar%23191!/:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
-- Initialization --
Details:
    Modules: 
        ADVAPI32.dll:Erweiterte Windows 32 Base-API:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        COMCTL32.dll:Bibliothek f r Steuerelemente:6.10 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        CRYPT32.dll:Krypto-API32:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        CRYPTBASE.DLL:Base cryptographic API DLL:10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        CRYPTSP.dll:Cryptographic Service Provider API:10.0.22621.3672 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        CoreMessaging.dll:Microsoft CoreMessaging Dll:10.0.22621.3672 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        CoreUIComponents.dll:Microsoft Core UI Components Dll:10.0.22621.3672:Microsoft Corporation
        DBGHELP.DLL:Windows Image Helper:10.0.22621.3593 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        DEVOBJ.dll:Device Information Set DLL:10.0.22621.2506 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        DNSAPI.dll:DNS-Client-API-DLL:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        GDI32.dll:GDI Client DLL:10.0.22621.3672 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        GLU32.dll:OpenGL-Hilfsprogrammbibliotheks-DLL:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        IMM32.DLL:Multi-User Windows IMM32 API Client DLL:10.0.22621.3374 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        IPHLPAPI.DLL:IP-Hilfs-API:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        KERNEL32.DLL:Client-DLL f r Windows NT-Basis-API:10.0.22621.3374 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        KERNELBASE.dll:Client-DLL f r Windows NT-Basis-API:10.0.22621.3374 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        MSASN1.dll:ASN.1 Runtime APIs:10.0.22621.2506 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        MSCTF.dll:MSCTF-Server-DLL:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        NSI.dll:NSI User-mode interface DLL:10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        NTASN1.dll:Microsoft ASN.1 API:10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        OLEAUT32.dll:OLEAUT32.DLL:10.0.22621.3672 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        Ole32.dll:Microsoft OLE f r Windows:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        POWRPROF.dll:Power Profile Helper DLL:10.0.22621.3374 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        PSAPI.DLL:Process Status Helper:10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        RPCRT4.dll:Remoteprozeduraufruf-Laufzeitumgebung:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        SETUPAPI.dll:Windows Setup-API:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Registry Object not present: narutomod:ua_oak_flag

        SHCORE.dll:SHCORE:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        SHELL32.dll:Allgemeine Windows-Shell-DLL:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        UMPDC.dll:User Mode Power Dependency Coordinator:10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        USER32.dll:Client-DLL f r Windows USER-API (mehrere Benutzer):10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        USERENV.dll:Userenv:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        VCRUNTIME140.dll:Microsoft  C Runtime Library:14.27.29016.0 built by: vcwrkspc:Microsoft Corporation
        VERSION.dll:Version Checking and File Installation Libraries:10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        WINHTTP.dll:Windows HTTP-Dienste:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        WINMM.dll:MCI API-DLL:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        WINTRUST.dll:Microsoft Trust Verification APIs:10.0.22621.3737 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        WS2_32.dll:Windows Socket 2.0-32-Bit-DLL:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        WSOCK32.dll:Windows Socket 32-Bit DLL:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        amdihk64.dll:Radeon Settings: Host Service:2,00,00,1788:Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
        amsi.dll:Anti-Malware Scan Interface:10.0.22621.3527 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        aswAMSI.dll:Avast AMSI COM object:24.5.9153.0:Gen Digital Inc.
        aswhook.dll:Avast Hook Library:24.5.9153.0:AVAST Software
        atig6pxx.dll:atiglpxx.dll:8.14.01.6564:Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
        atio6axx.dll:AMD OpenGL Driver:23.11.230906_ab0988b:Advanced Micro Devices, Inc
        bcrypt.dll:Bibliothek mit kryptografischen Primitiven von Windows:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        bcryptPrimitives.dll:Windows Cryptographic Primitives Library:10.0.22621.3672 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        cfgmgr32.dll:Configuration Manager DLL:10.0.22621.2506 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        clbcatq.dll:COM+ Configuration Catalog:2001.12.10941.16384 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        combase.dll:Microsoft COM f r Windows:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        dbgcore.DLL:Windows Core Debugging Helpers:10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        dhcpcsvc.DLL:DHCP Clientdienst:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        dhcpcsvc6.DLL:DHCPv6-Client:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        dinput8.dll:Microsoft DirectInput:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        dwmapi.dll:Microsoft Desktopfenster-Manager-API:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        dxcore.dll:DXCore:10.0.22621.3672 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        fwpuclnt.dll:FWP/IPsec Benutzermodus-API:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        gdi32full.dll:GDI Client DLL:10.0.22621.3672 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        glfw.dll:GLFW 3.4.0 DLL:3.4.0:GLFW
        icm32.dll:Microsoft Color Management Module (CMM):10.0.22621.3672 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        inputhost.dll:InputHost:10.0.22621.3672 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        java.dll:OpenJDK Platform binary:17.0.8.0:Eclipse Adoptium
        java.exe:OpenJDK Platform binary:17.0.8.0:Eclipse Adoptium
        jemalloc.dll
        jimage.dll:OpenJDK Platform binary:17.0.8.0:Eclipse Adoptium
        jli.dll:OpenJDK Platform binary:17.0.8.0:Eclipse Adoptium
        jna16278347338028349206.dll:JNA native library:6.1.4:Java(TM) Native Access (JNA)
        jsvml.dll:OpenJDK Platform binary:17.0.8.0:Eclipse Adoptium
        jvm.dll:OpenJDK 64-Bit server VM:17.0.8.0:Eclipse Adoptium
        kernel.appcore.dll:AppModel API Host:10.0.22621.2715 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        lwjgl.dll
        lwjgl_opengl.dll
        lwjgl_stb.dll
        management.dll:OpenJDK Platform binary:17.0.8.0:Eclipse Adoptium
        management_ext.dll:OpenJDK Platform binary:17.0.8.0:Eclipse Adoptium
        mdnsNSP.dll:Bonjour Namespace Provider:3,1,0,1:Apple Inc.
        mscms.dll:Microsoft-Farbabstimmungssystem-DLL:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        msvcp140.dll:Microsoft  C Runtime Library:14.27.29016.0 built by: vcwrkspc:Microsoft Corporation
        msvcp_win.dll:Microsoft  C Runtime Library:10.0.22621.3374 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        msvcrt.dll:Windows NT CRT DLL:7.0.22621.2506 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        mswsock.dll:Microsoft Windows Sockets 2.0-Dienstanbieter:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        napinsp.dll:E-Mail-Namenshimanbieter:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        ncrypt.dll:Windows NCrypt-Router:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        net.dll:OpenJDK Platform binary:17.0.8.0:Eclipse Adoptium
        nio.dll:OpenJDK Platform binary:17.0.8.0:Eclipse Adoptium
        nlansp_c.dll:NLA Namespace Service Provider DLL:10.0.22621.3672 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        ntdll.dll:DLL f r NT-Layer:10.0.22621.3374 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        opengl32.dll:OpenGL Client DLL:10.0.22621.3672 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        pdh.dll:Windows Unterst tzungs-DLL f r Leistungsdaten:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        perfos.dll:DLL f r Windows-Systemleistungsobjekte:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        perfproc.dll:DLL f r Windows-Verarbeitungsleistungsobjekte:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        pfclient.dll:SysMain Client:10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        pnrpnsp.dll:PNRP-Namespaceanbieter:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        profapi.dll:User Profile Basic API:10.0.22621.3527 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        rasadhlp.dll:Remote Access AutoDial Helper:10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        rsaenh.dll:Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider:10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        sechost.dll:Host for SCM/SDDL/LSA Lookup APIs:10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        shlwapi.dll:Shell Light-weight-Hilfsprogrammbibliothek:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        sunmscapi.dll:OpenJDK Platform binary:17.0.8.0:Eclipse Adoptium
        textinputframework.dll:"TextInputFramework.DYNLINK":10.0.22621.3672 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        ucrtbase.dll:Microsoft  C Runtime Library:10.0.22621.3593 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        uxtheme.dll:Microsoft UxTheme-Bibliothek:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        vcruntime140_1.dll:Microsoft  C Runtime Library:14.27.29016.0 built by: vcwrkspc:Microsoft Corporation
        verify.dll:OpenJDK Platform binary:17.0.8.0:Eclipse Adoptium
        win32u.dll:Win32u:10.0.22621.3733 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        windows.storage.dll:Microsoft WinRT Storage-API:10.0.22621.3527 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        winrnr.dll:LDAP RnR Provider DLL:10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        wintypes.dll:Windows-Basistypen-DLL:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        wshbth.dll:Windows Sockets Helper DLL:10.0.22621.3374 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        xinput1_4.dll:API f r Microsoft Common Controller:10.0.22621.2860 (WinBuild.160101.0800):Microsoft Corporation
        zip.dll:OpenJDK Platform binary:17.0.8.0:Eclipse Adoptium
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:182) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.2.8_mapped_parchment_2023.09.03-1.20.1-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?] {}
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?] {}
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?] {}
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.targets.CommonLaunchHandler.runTarget(CommonLaunchHandler.java:111) ~[fmlloader-1.20.1-47.2.8.jar:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.targets.CommonLaunchHandler.clientService(CommonLaunchHandler.java:99) ~[fmlloader-1.20.1-47.2.8.jar:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.targets.ForgeClientUserdevLaunchHandler.devService(ForgeClientUserdevLaunchHandler.java:19) ~[fmlloader-1.20.1-47.2.8.jar:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.targets.CommonDevLaunchHandler.lambda$makeService$7(CommonDevLaunchHandler.java:135) ~[fmlloader-1.20.1-47.2.8.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.launch(LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.java:30) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:53) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:71) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:108) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:78) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.BootstrapLaunchConsumer.accept(BootstrapLaunchConsumer.java:26) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.BootstrapLaunchConsumer.accept(BootstrapLaunchConsumer.java:23) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.bootstraplauncher.BootstrapLauncher.main(BootstrapLauncher.java:141) ~[bootstraplauncher-1.1.2.jar:?] {}


-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.20.1
    Minecraft Version ID: 1.20.1
    Operating System: Windows 11 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 17.0.8, Eclipse Adoptium
    Java VM Version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode, sharing), Eclipse Adoptium
    Memory: 254722016 bytes (242 MiB) / 511705088 bytes (488 MiB) up to 17163091968 bytes (16368 MiB)
    CPUs: 12
    Processor Vendor: AuthenticAMD
    Processor Name: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6-Core Processor              
    Identifier: AuthenticAMD Family 23 Model 113 Stepping 0
    Microarchitecture: Zen 2
    Frequency (GHz): 3.60
    Number of physical packages: 1
    Number of physical CPUs: 6
    Number of logical CPUs: 12
    Graphics card #0 name: AMD Radeon RX 6900 XT
    Graphics card #0 vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. (0x1002)
    Graphics card #0 VRAM (MB): 4095.00
    Graphics card #0 deviceId: 0x73bf
    Graphics card #0 versionInfo: DriverVersion=31.0.23013.1023
    Memory slot #0 capacity (MB): 32768.00
    Memory slot #0 clockSpeed (GHz): 2.13
    Memory slot #0 type: DDR4
    Memory slot #1 capacity (MB): 32768.00
    Memory slot #1 clockSpeed (GHz): 2.13
    Memory slot #1 type: DDR4
    Virtual memory max (MB): 69553.84
    Virtual memory used (MB): 34479.50
    Swap memory total (MB): 4096.00
    Swap memory used (MB): 1.82
    JVM Flags: 1 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump
    Launched Version: MOD_DEV
    Backend library: LWJGL version 3.3.1 build 7
    Backend API: AMD Radeon RX 6900 XT GL version 4.6.0 Core Profile Context 23.12.1.231124, ATI Technologies Inc.
    Window size: <not initialized>
    GL Caps: Using framebuffer using OpenGL 3.2
    GL debug messages: 
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'forge'
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    CPU: 12x AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6-Core Processor 
    ModLauncher: 10.0.9+10.0.9+main.dcd20f30
    ModLauncher launch target: forgeclientuserdev
    ModLauncher naming: mcp
    ModLauncher services: 
        mixin-0.8.5.jar mixin PLUGINSERVICE 
        eventbus-6.0.5.jar eventbus PLUGINSERVICE 
        fmlloader-1.20.1-47.2.8.jar slf4jfixer PLUGINSERVICE 
        fmlloader-1.20.1-47.2.8.jar object_holder_definalize PLUGINSERVICE 
        fmlloader-1.20.1-47.2.8.jar runtime_enum_extender PLUGINSERVICE 
        fmlloader-1.20.1-47.2.8.jar capability_token_subclass PLUGINSERVICE 
        accesstransformers-8.0.4.jar accesstransformer PLUGINSERVICE 
        fmlloader-1.20.1-47.2.8.jar runtimedistcleaner PLUGINSERVICE 
        modlauncher-10.0.9.jar mixin TRANSFORMATIONSERVICE 
        modlauncher-10.0.9.jar fml TRANSFORMATIONSERVICE 
    FML Language Providers: 
        minecraft@1.0
        lowcodefml@null
        javafml@null
    Mod List: 
        forge-1.20.1-47.2.8_mapped_parchment_2023.09.03-1.|Minecraft                     |minecraft                     |1.20.1              |COMMON_SET|Manifest: a1:d4:5e:04:4f:d3:d6:e0:7b:37:97:cf:77:b0:de:ad:4a:47:ce:8c:96:49:5f:0a:cf:8c:ae:b2:6d:4b:8a:3f
                                                          |Forge                         |forge                         |47.2.8              |COMMON_SET|Manifest: NOSIGNATURE
        main                                              |NarutoMod                     |narutomod                     |0.1-Infdev          |COMMON_SET|Manifest: NOSIGNATURE
    Crash Report UUID: add97825-9363-42b6-b19d-10a027cdbbf8
    FML: 47.2
    Forge: net.minecraftforge:47.2.8
[19:53:59] [Render thread/FATAL] [ne.mi.co.ForgeMod/]: Preparing crash report with UUID a2f21261-20f6-4856-a56f-1079b7861094
#@!@# Game crashed! Crash report saved to: #@!@# C:\Users\DinoG\IdeaProjects\NarutoMod\run\.\crash-reports\crash-2024-07-21_19.53.59-client.txt

> Task :runClient FAILED

